# Converging to 2 different values

Tags: math, coffeescript, numerical-methods, numerical-analysis

I have a piece of code that basically solves a system of 2 non-linear equations using a numeric approximation method.

Code:

```
l1 = 8
l2 = 10
x2 = 12.66
y2 = 11.928
maxError = 1e-30
maxIterations = 100

theta = 1: 0, 2: 0
theta1 = 0
theta2 = 0
i = 0
loop # Block 1
    i++
    theta1 = Math.acos (x2 - l2 * Math.cos theta2) / l1
    theta2 = Math.asin (y2 - l1 * Math.sin theta1) / l2
    break if Math.sqrt(Math.pow(theta[1] - theta1, 2) + Math.pow(theta[2] - theta2, 2)) <= maxError or i is maxIterations
    theta = 1: theta1, 2: theta2
console.log "Converged to first solution {theta1: #{theta1 * 180 / Math.PI}, theta2: #{theta2 * 180 / Math.PI}} in #{i} iterations."

theta = 1: 0, 2: 0
theta1 = 0
theta2 = 0
i = 0
loop # Block 2
    i++
    theta2 = Math.acos (x2 - l1 * Math.cos theta1) / l2
    theta1 = Math.asin (y2 - l2 * Math.sin theta2) / l1
    break if Math.sqrt(Math.pow(theta[1] - theta1, 2) + Math.pow(theta[2] - theta2, 2)) <= maxError or i is maxIterations
    theta = 1: theta1, 2: theta2
console.log "Converged to second solution {theta1: #{theta1 * 180 / Math.PI}, theta2: #{theta2 * 180 / Math.PI}} in #{i} iterations."
```

Output:

```
Converged to first solution {theta1: 60.004606260047474, theta2: 29.99652810779697} in 34 iterations.
Converged to second solution {theta1: 26.584939314539064, theta2: 56.593017466789554} in 35 iterations.
```

The 2 equations are:

```
8cos(θ₁) + 10cos(θ₂) = 12.66
8sin(θ₁) + 10sin(θ₂) = 11.928
```

In both the blocks (*Block 1* and *Block 2*), `θ₁` and `θ₂` both are set to `0` initially. Then one θ is substituted in one of the equations to find a value for the other θ. This 2nd θ is then substituted in the other equation to find a value for the first θ. This is done recursively, converging at `θ₁` and `θ₂`.

In the first block, I start with substituting `θ₂` as `0` and finding a value for `θ₁`. Vice-versa in the second block.

Now my question is, **Why do I end up with 2 different solutions when the only difference between the blocks is the starting variable?**

**PS**: I do understand that there would be 2 different solutions for the given set of equations. What I don't understand is the reason for arriving at the 2 different solutions just because I'm using different starting variables.

**PPS**: I did try starting with different initial values for `θ₁` and `θ₂` instead of `0`. That didn't change anything.

Answer (score 3):

if the following 2 expressions are not same,
        instead of    acos (x2 - l2 * Math.cos theta2) / l1 ,
                      acos ((x2 - l2 * Math.cos theta2) / l1) looks right.

applies to other 3 expressions also.

Comment: You are correct, the expressions are not the same: acos is not linear.

Answer (score 0):

You can analyze your methods as a kind of fixed-point method. A fixed-point method is one such that

```
v_{n+1} = f(v_{n})
```

In your case

```
v = (θ₁,θ₂)
```

and you rearranged your equations such that

```
f(v) = (acos(x₂ - l₂*cos(θ₂))/l₁, acos(y₂ - l₁*cos(θ₁))/l₂)
```

...more or less. As you use the already updated variable at the second calculation, it is the same as if you started with another `v0`, one where the second calculated variable is "one step ahead" the other. In the first case, your starting position is `(0,acos(y₂ - l₁)/l₂)`, and in the second in the starting position `(acos(x₂ - l₂)/l₁, 0)`. Despite what you said in your post-post-scriptum, it is a case of converging to different roots with different initial values.

It's hard to state why this happens. The basin of attraction of a root may have a weird boundary, as shown in the [Newton-Raphson](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton-Raphson#Basins_of_attraction) page in Wikipedia. You could try plotting the basins, selecting lots of initial starting points in your (θ₁,θ₂) domain and painting pixels of different colors depending to where they converge to.